Keycloak same realme but different clients
I have two apps: a customer app and a store app. I want to implement a system where if a user registers through the customer app, they cannot register in the store app, and vice versa. We have separate client configurations for each app. How can we differentiate between users to enforce this restriction?
I want to know how we can differentiate from token or something that its store person or customer

How do you want to match the users? Via email address? Username?
